# Accessing ListBox and other children in a LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm building an app where there's a arbitrarily long list of items where you can click on any of them and edit in place. As you edit any of these items I want to programmatically change focus to the next item in the list.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Margin="0,-10,0,-12">
                  <TextBox  x:Name ="tb" Text="{Binding TheText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

As the user types in the first TextBox and his text exceeds a certain # of characters (e.g. 138) I want to either add another item to the list as the next item and change focus to it, or, if there's already a next item, change focus to it.

I can't figure out how to get access to

1) The root list box
2) The TextBox control within an item given a list box item ID

Here's what I tried. When this runs, the `MainLongListSelector.SelectedITem = nextItem` causes the next item to be selected, but it does NOT get focus.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    var editBox = sender as TextBox;
    var selectedItem = MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel;
    if (editBox != null && selectedItem != null && editBox.Text.Length > 138) {
        // Move data at end to next box
        var overflow = editBox.Text.Substring(138, editBox.Text.Length - 138) ;
        selectedItem.Tweet = editBox.Text.Substring(0, 138);
        var nextItem = App.ViewModel.Items[int.Parse(selectedItem.ID) + 1];
        nextItem.Tweet = overflow;
        MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem = nextItem;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access the actual TextBox of that `nextItem` so I can explicitly set focus to it.

The same question applies if I just use `ListBox` but the issues are different. In the `ListBox` case when the `DataTemplate` contains a `TextBox` and focus is set, I don't get `SelectionChanged` events...which is why I'm sticking with `LongListSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to the TextBox get focus when the item item selected.

If this is what you need, here is a way to bind LisBoxItem.IsSelected To Element.Focus():
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adeb3e7f-16df-4c7b-b2d2-d7cdedb32ac0/setting-focus-of-a-textbox-inside-a-listbox?forum=wpf

Comment: That appears to apply to WPF. I don't think the relative binding stuff works in WP.